# Map-Reduce Query to Count Tags

Tags: javascript, couchdb, mapreduce

I have a database of documents which are tagged with keywords. I am trying to find (and then count) the unique tags which are used alongside each other. So for any given tag, I want to know what tags have been used alongside that tag.

For example, if I had one document which had the tags `[fruit, apple, plant]` then when I query `[apple]` I should get `[fruit, plant]`. If another document has tags `[apple, banana]` then my query for `[apple]` would give me `[fruit, plant, banana]` instead.

This is my map function which emits all the tags and their neighbours:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.tags) {
    doc.tags.forEach(function(tag1) {
      doc.tags.forEach(function(tag2) {
        emit(tag1, tag2);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

So in my example above, it would emit

```
apple -- fruit
apple -- plant
apple -- banana
fruit -- apple
fruit -- plant
...
```

My question is: what should my reduce function be? The reduce function should essentially filter out the duplicates and group them all together.

I have tried a number of different attempts, but my database server (CouchDB) keeps giving me a **Error: reduce_overflow_error. Reduce output must shrink more rapidly**.

---

**EDIT: I've found something that seems to work, but I'm not sure why.** I see there is an optional "rereduce" parameter to the reduce function call. If I ignore these special cases, then it stops throwing reduce_overflow_errors. Can anyone explain why? And also, should I just be ignoring these, or will this bite me in the ass later?

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  if(rereduce) return null; // Throws error without this.

  var a = [];
  values.forEach(function(tag) {
    if(a.indexOf(tag) < 0) a.push(tag);
  });
  return a;
}
```

Comment: As said by Jason, you should not use a reduce function to build an array of values. The result of reduce, [must have a small and predictable size](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html#lessons). With `if(rereduce) return null`, you are throwing part of the data in the toilet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is nice, and as I said in the comments, if it works for you, that's all you should care about. Here is an alternative implementation in case you ever bump into performance problems.

CouchDB likes tall lists, not fat lists. Instead of view rows keeping an array with every previous tag ever seen, this solution keeps the "sibling" tags in the **key** of the view rows, and then [group them together](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Grouping) to guarantee one unique sibling tag per row. Every row is just two tags, but there could be thousands or millions of rows: a tall list, which CouchDB prefers.

The main idea is to emit a 2-array of tag pairs. Suppose we have one doc, tagged `fruit, apple, plant`.

```
// Pseudo-code visualization of view rows (before reduce)
// Key         , Value
[apple, fruit ], 1
[apple, plant ], 1 // Basically this is every combination of 2 tags in the set.
[fruit, apple ], 1
[fruit, plant ], 1
[plant, apple ], 1
[plant, fruit ], 1
```

Next I tag something `apple, banana`.

```
// Pseudo-code visualization of view rows (before reduce)
// Key         , Value
[apple, banana], 1 // This is from my new doc
[apple, fruit ], 1
[apple, plant ], 1 // This is also from my new doc
[banana, apple], 1
[fruit, apple ], 1
[fruit, plant ], 1
[plant, apple ], 1
[plant, fruit ], 1
```

Why is the value always `1`? Because I can make a very simple built-in reduce function: `_sum` to tell me the count of all tag pairs. Next, query with `?group_level=2` and CouchDB will give you unique pairs, with a count of their total.

A map function to produce this kind of view might look like this:

```
function(doc) {
  // Emit "sibling" tags, keyed on tag pairs.
  var tags = doc.tags || []
  tags.forEach(function(tag1) {
    tags.forEach(function(tag2) {
      if(tag1 != tag2)
        emit([tag1, tag2], 1)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Jason. This is much more elegant, and gives me a count too. Thanks for the advice, I'll try to follow the "tall list" principle in future :)

Comment: I see I can also then query my view for a single key using that `?group=true&startkey=["apple"]&endkey=["apple",{}]` trick.

Comment: Yes, or you could also do `?group_level=1&key=["apple"]` which will bundle up all "apple" tags. CouchDB is relaxed.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a correct solution I am much happier with. The trick was that CouchDB must be set to `reduce_limit = false` so that it stops checking its heuristic against your query.

You can set this via Futon on http://localhost:5984/_utils/config.html under the **query_server_config** settings, by double clicking on the value.

Once that's done, here is my new map function which works better with the "re-reducing" part of the reduce function:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.tags) {
    doc.tags.forEach(function(tag1) {
      doc.tags.forEach(function(tag2) {
        emit(tag1, [tag2]); // Array with single value
      });
    });
  }
}
```

And here is the reduce function:

```
function(keys, values) {
  var a = [];
  values.forEach(function(tags) {
    tags.forEach(function(tag) {
      if(a.indexOf(tag) < 0) a.push(tag);
    });
  });
  return a;
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks to this comment that helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456682/return-unique-values-by-key-in-couchdb#comment6920983_5460779

Comment: That solution will eventually not scale. Reduce functions must reduce the amount of data, not simply reformat it (by maintaining an always-growing array). However, CouchDB is relaxed, so I encourage you to stick with this if you know that it will not be a problem. I will post an answer with an alternative you can keep in the back of your mind for later, of you ever need to revisit this.